# Rotating / Moving Bone Scales Mesh

Tags: bones

Am learning about bones, so created a very basic rig.  When I rotate or move my foot bone, it scales that part of the mesh.

My object scaling is set to 1 ((ctrl + a) read about this from another question).

Here is a GIF showing the issue, and the weight paint for the foot.  Am not sure how to fix this.  I recreated my armature a number of times, but the same thing happens with the foot bones.

[image: GIF]

Comment: Can you upload your .blend?

Comment: I think this is a normal behavior as your vertices share the exact same weights for each bone... Imagine a vertex at the extremity, for one bone it is said "hey come we rotate", but for the other bone "hey no.. stay in place"... so the vertex falls in between

Comment: @lemon That's exactly what the issue was.  Thanks.  Didn't think about that at all.  I unpainted the vertices, and now it doesn't scale when moving the foot bone.  Thanks :)

Comment: @lemon If you post that as a solution, I can accept it :)

Comment: @JacketPotatoeFan, I won't because I wanted to find the real calculation to explain it more clearly. But I don't know it for now.